# Is it possible to verify 'referential integrity' of xml data against an xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to verify 'referential integrity' of xml data against an xsd?  Or is an xsd merely a data format definition.

If I have an xsd that defines a parent/child relationship does validation of an xml document against that xsd guarantee that the pre-requisite data for the relationship to be complete, exists?

For example, let's say I have a SCHOOL and a STUDENT.  Every STUDENT must have a valid SCHOOL_ID.  Let's say I have one SCHOOL defined with a SCHOOL_ID of '001' but a STUDENT defined with SCHOOL_ID of '002' but that SCHOOL_ID doesn't exist under SCHOOL.  Will that xml document's validation against the xsd that defines that required relationship fail?

Comment: Could you edit your question and show actual XML instead of using a verbal description of the problem?

Comment: Some questions are clearer without the formatting 'jargon' IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

One can define a key (either using xsd:key or xsd:unique) and then reference it using an xsd:keyref.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="sample">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SCHOOL" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="STUDENT" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="SCHOOL_ID" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="PKSchools">
            <xsd:selector xpath="SCHOOL"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="."/>
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:keyref name="FKStudentSchool" refer="PKSchools">
            <xsd:selector xpath="STUDENT/SCHOOL_ID"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="."/>
        </xsd:keyref>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

[image: Schema diagram]

This sample XML will fail validation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<sample xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SCHOOL>001</SCHOOL>
    <STUDENT>
        <SCHOOL_ID>002</SCHOOL_ID>
    </STUDENT>
</sample>
```

The error message (may vary):

> Error occurred while loading [], line 8 position 3 The key sequence
>   '002' in 'PKSchools' Keyref fails to refer to some key.